# "java: package org.junit does not exist" even though it's in Maven pom

Tags: maven, junit, configuration, dependencies

I get "java: package org.junit does not exist"  in my project and it's driving me crazy.  I have JUnit as an external library and it still isn't recognizing that.  I am trying to set up a simple "Hello World" app in IntelliJ Idea.

Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>untitled</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>untitled</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

UPDATE: I was able to run the same exact project on my other computer.  This is strange.

Comment: Remove your m2 repo, and post the result of `mvn -U clean install`.

Comment: @Tunaki I am using the builtin maven of intellij idea.  Doing that works on my other Mac.

Comment: I suggest you remove your local m2 repo as it may be corrupt. This means removing the directory ~/.m2/repository (this is the default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
mvn idea:idea
```

It will generate the files needed for your IntelliJ IDEA project.

Comment: I did that, and all the necessary files were generated.  Whenever I tried to compile it in my Intellij IDEA project, the built error still says pack org.unit does not exist.  The library is sitting in my external libraries folder though.

Comment: Do you have tried to compile your project in command line ? If it doesn't work, I guess it's due to a corrupted jar in your local Maven repository. Removing all dependencies in .m2 is not sufficient in some cases. I get a quite similar issue. It was due to Maven version directly. After upgrading Maven and mvn clean install -U, it was ok.

Comment: Simply deleting the .m2 directory fixed it for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Simply deleting the .m2 directory fixed it for me.

*klamse Sep 30 '15 at 1:41*

We should put it in the answers list. This really helps! Thanks.